# c++ pthread: how to set io_service.run() as parameter in pthread_create?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, callback, pthreads

I want to run a callback function in a pthread.

I am currently stuck at the following code:

```
//maintest.cpp
....
main{
...
//setting up the callback function SimT:
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io);
SimT d(t);

//calling io.run() in another thread with io.run()
pthread_t a;
pthread_create( &a, NULL, io.run(),NULL); ----->Here I dont know how to pass the io.run() function
...
//other stuff that will be executed during io.run()
}
```

How should I specify io.run() in the pthread_create argument?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass a pointer to a non-member function, for example:

```
extern "C" void* run(void* io) {
    static_cast<io_service*>(io)->run();
    return nullptr; // TODO report errors
}

pthread_create(&a, nullptr, run, &io);
```

Of course, these days there's no need to muck around with native threading libraries:

```
std::thread thread([&]{io.run();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to create a functor object and pass that in. For more information, check: [C++ Functors - and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)

Edit: If you're using C++11, this solution will be much cleaner: [passing Lambda to pthread_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308401/passing-lambda-to-pthread-create)

Comment: @user2212461: Not directly, since that's a C library which doesn't know about C++ classes and member functions. You'll need to write a C-compatible function to wrap up the member function call.